# Application failed to start Qt platform plugins Windows

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Installed PostgreSQL 11.1 and pgAdmin 4 on my Laptop with Windows 10. All OK.

Then moved to server with Windows Server 2008

[image]

And I followed the same installation but got Application failed...

[image]

I appreciate all the help I get.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Server 2008 SP2 is not supported. But 2008R2 (server) and above are supoorted